# SAML SP Login - How does Localhost address get resolved

Tags: oauth-2.0, saml-2.0

Currently, using Okta (SAML2, OAuth2) or Linkedin (OAuth2), or other SSO providers you can do an SSO for your commericial/personal applications.

In SAML/SSO - The IdP sends the assertion response to Assertion Consumption Service (ACS) URL (typically, a deep link in your application) where you determine whether access should be granted or not.

Quite often, a personal application uses localhost address (e.g. `http://localhost/SSODeepLink/?resp%3Dsomething`). But this `localhost` is `local` to the user, not to the IdP. My curiosity is, how do we bind `localhost` to correct DNS/IP Address for resolution. It's more of my curiousity as the process clearly works, but I don't understand how.

Any guidance is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

In case of SAML the IdP need not talk to the SP when so called 'front channel bindings' are being used as in that case all SAML messages are transferred via the user-agent (e.g. browser).
In case of OAuth2 it's basically the same as a OAuth2 client has to specify a `redirectURI`. That redirectURI can use `localhost` just fine.

Comment: Okay, could kindly refer me to this front channel binding thingy. I guess this is not directly at the application layer, so I am not familiar with it..

Comment: Bindings define the way SAML messages are transferred between SAML entities and typically they are specified in the entity meta data.
E.g. when the following is specified in SP meta data ...
    `<AssertionConsumerService index="0" isDefault="true" Binding="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST" Location="SOME_ENDPOINT_URL"/>`
The IdP can only use an HTTP POST request to send the SAMLResponse to the SP. This is typically achieved by a self-submitting HTML form.